Python flask api request to Microsoft Graph API node working from Next JS
I have an app built with Next.js that interacts with a Python Flask API to generate a DOCX file and upload it to OneDrive via the Microsoft Graph API. Here's an overview of the relevant code:
1.Next.js Code (TypeScript):
import toPascalCase from "@/libs/toPascalCase";
import axios from "axios";

const DownloadTemplate = async (suratData: any, accessToken: String) => {
  try {
    const locResponse = await fetch("http://ip-api.com/json/");
    const locData = await locResponse.json();
    const city = locData.city || "Jakarta"; // Default to Jakarta if city is not found

    const requestBody = {
      template: "Memo",
      kepada:
        suratData?.surat?.kepadaId.map((k: any) => k.name).join(", ") || "",
      dari: suratData?.surat?.dariId.name || "",
      perihal: suratData?.konten?.perihal.name || "",
      sifat: suratData?.konten?.sifat.name || "",
      lampiran: suratData?.konten?.lampiran?.name || "-",
      tgl: suratData?.surat?.tanggal
        ? new Date(suratData.surat.tanggal).toLocaleDateString("id-ID", {
            day: "2-digit",
            month: "long",
            year: "numeric",
          })
        : "",
      Tempat: city,
      jabatan: toPascalCase(suratData?.surat?.dariId?.jabatan || ""),
      name: toPascalCase(suratData?.surat?.dariId?.name || ""),
      stringforqr: "testing dari front end node",
    };

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(requestBody));

    console.log("Request Body:", requestBody);

    const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getTemplate', requestBody, {
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error downloading template:", error);
  }
};

export default DownloadTemplate;

2. Python Flask Code:
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import database
from docx2pdf import convert
import os
import tempfile
import pythoncom
import logging
import pythoncom
import qrcode
import requests
import tempfile
import json
from PIL import Image
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
# app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


def fill_invitation(template_path, output_path, data, qr_code_path=None):
    doc = Document(template_path)
    # doc = template_path
    # data['tgl'] = datetime.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")

    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key in paragraph.text:
                for index, run in enumerate(paragraph.runs):
                    newkey = '{{' + key + '}}'
                    if paragraph.runs[index-1].text == '{{' and run.text == key:
                        run.text = run.text.replace(key, value)
                        paragraph.runs[index-1].text = ''
                        paragraph.runs[index+1].text = ''
                    elif newkey == run.text:
                        if newkey == "qr":
                            run.text
                        run.text = run.text.replace(newkey, value)
                        
    for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for key, value in data.items():
                        if key in paragraph.text:
                            for index, run in enumerate(paragraph.runs):
                                newkey = '{{' + key + '}}'
                                if paragraph.runs[index-1].text == '{{' and paragraph.runs[index+1].text == '}}' and run.text == key:
                                    run.text = run.text.replace(key, value)
                                    paragraph.runs[index-1].text = ''
                                    paragraph.runs[index+1].text = ''
                                elif newkey == run.text:
                                    run.text = run.text.replace(newkey, value)
                                    
    if qr_code_path:
            inserted = False
            for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
                if "{{qr}}" in paragraph.text:
                    logging.debug("QR code placeholder '{{qr}}' found.")
                    paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("{{qr}}", "")
                    run = paragraph.add_run()
                    run.add_picture(qr_code_path, width=Inches(1.3))
                    inserted = True
                    logging.debug("QR code inserted into paragraph.")

            if not inserted:
                logging.debug("QR code placeholder '{{qr}}' not found in the document.")
                
    doc.save(output_path)

@app.route('/getTemplate', methods=['POST'])

def docsFilling():
    data = request.get_json()
    # data = json.loads(request.form.get('data'))
    
    accessToken = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    print('data ================================== > ', data)
    print('accessToken ================================== > ', accessToken)
    templateData = data.get('template')
    listTipeSurat = database.getData(templateData)
    template = "retrieved_file.docx"

    Logo_link = 'Logo_PGASOL.jpg'
    stringqr = data['stringforqr']
    basewidth = 200

    logo = Image.open(Logo_link)
    wpercent = (basewidth / float(logo.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(logo.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    logo = logo.resize((basewidth, hsize))

    QRcode = qrcode.QRCode(
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H
    )
    QRcode.add_data(stringqr)
    QRcode.make()
    QRcolor = 'Black'
    QRimg = QRcode.make_image(
        fill_color=QRcolor, back_color="white").convert('RGB')

    pos = ((QRimg.size[0] - logo.size[0]) // 2,
           (QRimg.size[1] - logo.size[1]) // 2)
    QRimg.paste(logo, pos)
    
    try:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png', dir='./temp/qr') as temp_qr:
            qr_code_path = temp_qr.name
            QRimg.save(qr_code_path)

        with open(template, "wb") as f:
            f.write(listTipeSurat.fileTemplate)

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.docx', dir='./temp/docs') as temp_docx:
            output_path = temp_docx.name
            print('output_path =====> ', output_path)
            fill_invitation(template, output_path, data, qr_code_path)
        
        with open(output_path, 'rb') as item:
            media_content = item.read()
        
        x = requests.put('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/special/approot:/test15.docx:/content', 
                                 headers={'Authorization': accessToken, 
                                          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}, 
                                 data=media_content)
        dataContent = x.json()
        return dataContent
        

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e), 500

    finally:
        # Ensure temporary files are cleaned up
        try:
            if os.path.exists(output_path):
                os.remove(output_path)
            if os.path.exists(qr_code_path):
                os.remove(qr_code_path)
        except PermissionError:
            pass  # Handle the permission error or log it
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
    app.run(debug=True)

the purpose of my code is to call the endpoint in my python to use the ruqest data that send from next js to python and turn them into a docx that has been auto filled and then upload it to onedrive through microsoft graph api.
Issue:
When I call the Python API endpoint from my Next.js app, I receive the following error from the Microsoft Graph API:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "innerError": {
            "client-request-id": "4a9e1e4f-1cc0-4725-944e-a95ec0d5e409",
            "date": "2024-08-08T13:22:57",
            "request-id": "4a9e1e4f-1cc0-4725-944e-a95ec0d5e409"
        },
        "message": "Item not found"
    }
}

but when i test it through POSTMAN app it run without any issue the docs was created and uploaded to my one drive.
Questions:

Could this issue be related to CORS problems, or is it a code-level issue?
What steps can I take to troubleshoot and resolve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

What do u mean with "when I try it through POSTMAN app"? Do u call your Python API using Postman or directly call the Microsoft API?

yes i call my python API using Postman. i meant everything works perfectly if i call from postman as you can see the endpoint that im calling is @app.route('/getTemplate', methods=['POST']) that run docsFilling() function which return whatever response from Graph API which i declare the variable as x when i call the endpoint POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/getTemplate using from my front end app (Next.js) the x ( my variable that contain response from Graph API ) it return the error i wrote above but if i call it postman using postman with same object it return successful response from the graphAPI

First off, the request you are making to /me/drive/{some-id}/content does not exists
For content of an item you should be calling one of
PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
PUT /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content

That said, the request you made also has just the claims scp=User.Read profile openid email while Files.ReadWrite is the minimum permission needed.
My suggestion is to first check the URL being called and ensure its one of the ones listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
Then check for Files.ReadWrite permission in your app. It should be added as delegated permission on Entra Portal.
